# Struct with array members

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, struct

I have Material struct which stores three arrays: ambient, diffuse and specular.
I'm using it to store information about material of the single object.
Header file:

```
struct Material
{
  float (&ambient)[4], (&diffuse)[4], (&specular)[4];
  Material(float (&ambient)[4], float (&diffuse)[4], float (&specular)[4]);
  float* Ambient();
  float* Diffuse();
  float* Specular();
}
```

Source file:

```
Material::Material(float (&_ambient)[4], float (&_diffuse)[4], float (&_specular)[4]): ambient{_ambient}, diffuse{_diffuse}, specular{_specular}{}

float* Material::Ambient()
{
  return ambient;
}

float* Material::Diffuse()
{
  return diffuse;
}

float* Material::Specular()
{
  return specular;
}
```

I have this function to initialize object:

```
float random(float min, float max)
{
  return min + static_cast<float> (rand()) / static_cast<float> (RAND_MAX / (max - min));
}

void createBall(int)
{
  float ambient[] = {random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1};
  float diffuse[] = {random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1};
  float specular[] = {random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1};
  (...)
  ballMaterials.push_back(Material(ambient, diffuse, specular));
}
```

And drawing function:

```
void drawBall(float radius, Vector3& position, Material material, Rigidbody rigidbody)
{
  (...)
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_AMBIENT,material.Ambient());
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE,material.Diffuse());
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,material.Specular());
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SHININESS,high_shininess);
  glPushMatrix();
  (...)
  glScalef(radius, radius, radius);
  glCallList(index);
  glPopMatrix();
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Something is very wrong because ball is flat and red, not in randomized color. I guess I've implemented struct in wrong way but I'm not sure how to fix that (array members). Could you help me?

Comment: Refering to local variables to vanish isn't good. Try copying the contents of arrays instead of having references.

Comment: You don't have `Material` struct which stores three arrays: you only have struct which stores three *reference to* arrays.

Comment: Use `std::array<float, 4>` instead of dumb float arrays and float pointers, and all of your troubles will go away.

Answer (score 2):

I will expand on my comment concerning the usage of [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and show you the example of what you are trying to do, but instead use the `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

typedef std::array<float, 4> FloatArray4;
struct Material
{
   FloatArray4 ambient, diffuse, specular;
   Material(const FloatArray4& ambient_, const FloatArray4& diffuse_, 
            const FloatArray4& specular_) : ambient(ambient_), diffuse(diffuse_), specular(specular_){}

   FloatArray4& Ambient() { return ambient; }
   FloatArray4& Diffuse() { return diffuse; }
   FloatArray4& Specular() { return specular; }
};

float random(float minVal, float maxVal)
{
   return minVal + static_cast<float> (rand()) / static_cast<float> (RAND_MAX / (maxVal - minVal));
}

std::vector<Material> ballMaterials;

void createBall(int)
{
  FloatArray4 ambient = {{random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1}};
  FloatArray4 diffuse = {{random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1}};
  FloatArray4 specular = {{random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1}};
  ballMaterials.push_back(Material(ambient, diffuse, specular));
}

void drawBall(float radius, Vector3& position, Material material, Rigidbody rigidbody)
{
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_AMBIENT,material.Ambient().data());
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE,material.Diffuse().data());
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,material.Specular().data());
}

int main()
{
   createBall(10);
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/WfVuCP)

Note that there are no pointers to deal with.

The `std::array` is passed by reference, and on the functions that return the array, a reference to the existing `std::array` is returned.  You can add other functions to return copies of the `std::array` if this is another requirement.

Also, note the `std::array::data()` function that gives access to the underlying array.

Answer (score 1):

Your original structure contains references to arrays (that's what the ampersand does in the member declaration.)  That means the arrays do not actually live inside the structure.  They are elsewhere in memory and the structure contains a hidden pointer to their actual location (reference = hidden pointer [but don't tell anyone])

Thus your structure is only valid as long as the real arrays are valid.  Since you assign local variables to them in the CreateBall method, as soon as you return from this method your structures are no longer valid.  *Anything* could happen.

The simplest solution is to switch to using `std::array<float, 4>` to declare your members.  It handles all the messy details for you. If you don't want to take that approach, you will have to declare your member arrays without ampersands, and actually copy the floats from the arguments to your constructor into the items in your member arrays.

Note:

Others have pointed this out in comments.  I'm just consolidating this into an answer (note if you made one of the comments and want the rep, feel free to post an answer and I'll remove mine.)